# How to specify jq output fields from variable in bash?

Tags: bash, jq

given the following (simplified) json file:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "datum": "2023-01-11 00:00:00",
            "prijs": "0.005000",
            "prijsZP": "0.161550",
            "prijsEE": "0.181484",
            "prijsTI": "0.160970",
        },
        {
            "datum": "2023-01-11 01:00:00",
            "prijs": "0.000000",
            "prijsZP": "0.155500",
            "prijsEE": "0.175434",
            "prijsTI": "0.154920",
        }
  ]
}
```

I want to specify in my jq command which fields to retreive, i.e. only "datum" and "prijsTI". But on another moment this selection will be different.

I use the following command to gather all the fields, but would like to set the field selection via a variable:

`cat data.json |jq -r '.data[]|[.datum, .prijsTI]|@csv'`

I already tried using arguments, but this did not work :-(

`myJQselect=".datum, .prijsTI"`
`cat data.json |jq -r --arg myJQselect "$myJQselect" '.data[$myHour |tonumber]|[$myJQselect]|@csv'`

gives the following result:  `".datum, .prijs"` instead of the correct values.

Would this be possible?

Thanks,

Jeroen

Comment: The _whole point_ of `--arg` is content given therein is treated as data, not code.

Comment: Anyhow -- is the number of fields constant? (Is it always exactly two?)

Comment: BTW, your data isn't valid JSON as given; it has commas where they aren't allowed.

Comment: Charles, the number of fields is now 13, but expected to be growing in the (near) future. That's why I want to make my script more flexible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `--args` option to provide a variable number of fields to query, then use the `$ARGS.positional` array to retrieve them:

```bash
jq -r '.data[] | [.[$ARGS.positional[]]] | @csv' data.json --args datum prijsTI
```

```
"2023-01-11 00:00:00","0.160970"
"2023-01-11 01:00:00","0.154920"
```